# macros with arguments in gnuplot

Tags: function, macros, command, gnuplot

Is there a way in gnuplot I can combine gnuplot commands and functions in a macro?

One example would be the following:

In gnuplot I can do for instance

```
set_output = "set output"
pdf_output(x) = x.".pdf"
@set_output pdf_output(mypdf)
```

And this will be equivalent to the line

```
set output "mypdf.pdf"
```

Is there a way I can define a function such that

```
somefunction(x) = set output x.".pdf"
@somefunction(mypdf)
```

would be equivalent to the same thing?

set output "mypdf.pdf"

Answer (score 4):

For that you can use `eval`:

```
out(x) = sprintf("set output '%s.pdf'", x)
eval(out("file"))
```